How can I prevent macOS from rearranging windows?
macOS appears to rearrange windows, sometimes. I haven't figured out the exact circumstances, but it always seems to occur while the system is idle, usually long enough for the external monitor to going into low-power use.
The system is plugged in at all times (i.e., it is not on battery) and the external monitor is also similarly plugged in at all times.
Essentially, I stand up for a break, sit back down, and I can no longer find my Terminal window, for example, because macOS has moved it to the internal screen & buried it beneath other windows on that display.

When the external monitor goes into low-power mode, it stops communicating with the Mac and essentially drops out of the system. When this happens, macOS throws all the windows open on this external screen onto the internal screen. It's not logical to have a window 'disappear', because the monitor is disconnected. No matter how many external monitors you connect, it is all one big Desktop anyway. Suggestions: • turn off low-power mode on the monitor • put the system to sleep  Tell us which model of Mac, external screen manufacturer, connection (HDMI, TBolt) macOS version, etc.
